# Setting up a Linux Partition

Tags: debian, linux-mint

I've recently learned that I need to install "Debian 7.0" on my machine. I know very little about Linux. However, I do know there are a variety of distributions. From my understanding, some of these distributions are built on top of others. This has lead me to three questions:

1. I am somebody that likes a good user experience.I see LinuxMint Debian. Can I use that and still be compliant with the Debian 7.0 requirement?
2. What is the difference between LinuxMint Debian and plain old LinuxMint?
3. I want to have a shared drive between my Windows world and Debian environment. This drive will only be used to share files. What format must I format that drive in?

Thank you

Comment: 3. May other people propose you FAT, NTFS is working somewhat well enough for me.

Comment: You would have to use an ext file system such as Ext3 or Ext4, I don't think NTFS or FAT would work with linux unless you installed side by side on a windows partition

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends how strict the requirement was meant. You can have a good user experience with Debian as well, Debian provides several desktop environments to chose from.
2. Mint is Ubuntu based, where as MintDebian is Debian based.
3. You need to chose a file system that can be read resp. written from both sides. Without additional software windows is somewhat limited in supporting other file systems than FAT or NTFS.

You may install Debian (or Windows) in a virtual machine like this both OS run at the same time on your computer. This gives you the possibility to use a network protocol for sharing your files between both OS'.